# some bug when i add event to same class diff ID

Tags: javascript, ajax

There have some bug in this demo .
I want add same event to same class but diff ID .
Code Like this

```
    var self;
    var id;
    var result;
    var myArray=document.getElementsByClassName("tipDiv");
    for (var i=0;i<myArray.length;i++)
        {
            document.getElementsByClassName("tipDiv")[i].onmouseover=(function(num){
                return function() {            
                    $(this).myHoverTip("hoverDiv","");
                    }
            })(i);   
            document.getElementsByClassName("tipDiv")[i].onmouseout=(function(num){
                return function() {            
                    $(this).cleanHover("hoverDiv");
                    }
            })(i);        
        }


$.fn.myHoverTip = function(divId, value) 
   {
        var div = $("#" + divId); 
        div.css("position", "absolute");
        self = $(this); 
        id = self.attr("id");
        self.hover(function() 
            {
            div.css("display", "block");
            var p = self.position(); 
            var x = p.left + self.width();
            var docWidth = $(document).width();
            if (x > docWidth - div.width() - 20) 
                {
                x = p.left - div.width();
            }
            div.css("left", x);
            div.css("top", p.top);
                function showCustomer(str)
                {
                var xmlhttp;
                if (str=="")
                  {
                  result="";
                  return;
                  }
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                  }
                else
                  {// code for IE6, IE5
                  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                  }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                  {
                  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                    {
                    result=xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                  }
                xmlhttp.open("GET","getbrand.asp?q="+str,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
                div.html(id+result+myArray.length);
                }
            showCustomer(id);

            },

    function() {
        div.css("display", "none");
        div.html("");
    }
    );

 return this;
}
```

please help me fix the bug...
It's doesn't work like i want.  First mousemoveover the hover doesn't work .And second get the wrong value. At third moveover get the right value . And i move to next DIV . It will be get the last value. Please help me ! Sorry for my english.

Comment: first of all you don't have to do the document.getElementsByClassName("tipDiv") again in the forloop. this is already stored in the myArray, so you can just use myArray[i].. But why don't you use jquery and the hover function? http://api.jquery.com/hover/. With this you can just select your class: $(".hoverDiv").hover(...)

Answer (score 0):

first of all you don't have to do the `document.getElementsByClassName("tipDiv")` again in the forloop. this is already stored in the `myArray`, so you can just use `myArray[i]`..

But why don't you use jquery and the hover function? [api.jquery.com/hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover). With this you can just select your class:

> $(".hoverDiv").hover(...)

This will make it easier for you I guess..

or use the mouseOver function from jquery:
http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/